# Create a list of user names and Balance using C

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am trying to create an list of user names and balance. The code compiles perfectly fine, but there is a logic error that I am not able to figure out. 
Basically the code is supposed to take an time-stamp, user name and a balance. Some conditions are checked for each of the input. At the end of the file, the computer should print out the most recent balance for the associated username.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//function declaration
int checkTimeStamp(int currentTS, int prevTS);
int checkBalance(float currentBal, float prevBal);

//Nodes for each List
struct node
{
    char userName[31];
    float balance;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    //Float and int variables
    float bal;
    int timeStamp;
    int listCount = 0; //Keep Track of the number of nodes
    int iEach = 0;
    int check = 0; //user for validating input string
    int prevTS = 0;
    int prevBal = 0;
    int checkBal;
    int checkTS;

    //String variables
    char userID[31];
    char input[130];


    //Node variables
    struct node root = { "", 0, NULL};// declare and initialize the first structure
    struct node* freeNode = NULL;// declare a pointer and initialize it null. use for freeing memory later
    struct node* pNode = &root;// declare a pointer and initialize it to point to the first structure

    while( fgets(input, 130, stdin) )
    {
        check = sscanf(input, "%d %s %f" , &timeStamp, userID, &bal); //checking if the user has entered the right values
        //printf("%d\n", check);

        if( check == 0 ) //checking if timestamp was integer
        {
            printf("Invalid time\n");
        }
        else if( check == 2 ) //checking if balance was float
        {
            printf("Illegal balance\n");
            prevTS = timeStamp;
        }
        else //if check >= 3
        {
            //pNode->next = malloc ( sizeof( struct node));// allocate memory for the next structure
            checkBal = checkBalance(bal, prevBal);
            checkTS = checkTimeStamp(timeStamp, prevTS);
            if(checkTS == 1)
            {
                printf("Non-monotonic timestamps\n");  
            }
            else if( checkBal == -1 )
            {
                printf("Debit!!!\n");  
                prevTS = timeStamp;
                listCount++;
                strcpy(pNode->userName,userID); // use the pointer to assign the userID
                pNode->balance = bal;
                pNode->next = malloc ( sizeof ( struct node));// allocate memory for the next structure

            }
            else if( checkBal == 1 )
            {
                printf("Suspiciously large balance change\n");
                prevTS = timeStamp;
                prevBal = bal;
                listCount++;
                strcpy(pNode->userName,userID); // use the pointer to assign the userID
                pNode->balance = bal;
                pNode->next = malloc ( sizeof ( struct node));// allocate memory for the next structure
            }
            else if( checkBal == 2 && checkTS == 2)
            {
                printf("Ok\n");
                prevTS = timeStamp;
                prevBal = bal;
                listCount++;
                strcpy(pNode->userName,userID); // use the pointer to assign the userID
                pNode->balance = bal;
                pNode->next = malloc ( sizeof ( struct node));// allocate memory for the next structure
            }

        }

    }
    pNode = &root; // set the pointer to the original structure root
    for ( iEach = 0; iEach < listCount; iEach++) // loop through each structure. ilistCount holds the number of structures
    {
        printf("Location number %d is : (%s,%.2f)\n", iEach + 1, pNode->userName, pNode->balance);
        pNode = pNode->next; // set the pointer to the next structure

    }

    pNode = root.next; // set the pointer to the first allocated structure
    for ( iEach = 1; iEach < listCount; iEach++) // loop through each structure
        //start with 1 as the first structure was not allocate and does not need to be freed. ilistCount holds the number of structures
    {
        freeNode = pNode->next; // set the free pointer to the next structure
        free ( pNode); // free the memory for the structure
        pNode = freeNode; // point to the free pointer
    }

}


//Functions
int checkTimeStamp(int currentTS, int prevTS)
{
    if( prevTS >= currentTS)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 2;  
    }  
}


int checkBalance(float currentBal, float prevBal)
{
    if( abs(currentBal - prevBal) >= 1000)
    {
        return 1;  
    }
    else if ( currentBal < 0)
    {
        return -1; 
    }
    else
    {
        return 2;  
    }
}
```

When the input is :

```
Testing 234 234.153
1235 Mega0123test -x-0.5
3600 godzilla 300
36000 godzilla 299
36001 godzilla 2000
36002 godzilla 0
36003 godzilla -10
36004 godzilla1 10
36005 godzilla2 10
36006 godzilla3 10 
1000 innocent 69
^D
```

The out put should be:

```
Illegal balance
Ok
Ok
Suspiciously large balance change
Suspiciously large balance change
Debit!!!
Ok
Ok
Ok
Non-monotonic timestamps
Invalid time
Non-monotonic timestamps
godzilla 0
godzilla -10
godzilla1 10
godzilla2 10
godzilla3 10
```

But I get

```
Illegal balance
Ok
Ok
Suspiciously large balance change
Suspiciously large balance change
Debit!!!
Ok
Ok
Ok
Non-monotonic timestamps
Invalid time
Non-monotonic timestamps
Location number 1 is : (godzilla3,10.00)
Location number 2 is : (,0.00)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: @user3121023 Okaaaay so that solved it :D Could you make that an answer :)

Comment: Also, since you are relying on a linked-list of `struct node`, you would benefit from creating a function or two to help manage the list. A quick search or two will give you ideas for create_node and add_node functions. Also take care to insure that the information you use is for a **single, non-circular linked-list**. If your list size grows beyond 1M or so nodes, you may then want to look into a circular double linked-list with node->prev and node->next pointers to allow iterating fwd and backwards to reduce the iterations required on each search, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a logic error (at least, not the type you mean). The message

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

means that the program accessed some memory it shouldn't have, causing the operating system to kill it. You should load your program in a debugger or memory checker, then step through your program looking for where the illegal access occurred.

On Linux, a good debugger is *gdb*, the GNU Debugger. A memory checker I can equally recommend is *valgrind* (and friends). Neither of these are installed by default, but are available by e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install gdb valgrind
```

Explaining how to use these would be a very long answer, but there's some good tutorials out there, just use a search engine.

Comment: Where can I do that? Is there any default application in Ubuntu that does it? @Michael

Answer (score 0):

In your first `while` loop, you never change `pNode` so it always points to `root`.

None of the malloc'd nodes are initialized.

The later loops iterate into uninitialized memory.

@user3121023 give the solution in a comment to the question.